Uniswap v3 Mainnet vs Sepolia EvmError: Revert
I'm struggling to solve EvmError: Revert, while calling createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary function on Uniswap v3 NonfungiblePositionManager contract. I have wrote function that contains this code:
uint160 private constant INITIAL_PRICE = 7922816251426433759354395;
uint24 private constant FEE = 3000;
address i_nftPositionManager = 0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88; // Mainnet
address i_wrappedNativeToken = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2; // Mainnet


INonfungiblePositionManager(i_nftPositionManager).createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary(newERC20Address, i_wrappedNativeToken, FEE, INITIAL_PRICE);

And I'm testing it using foundry framework. Everything works perfectly fine when I'm testing it on forked Sepolia network, but it is reverting while testing on forked Ethereum Mainnet or Polygon Mainnet. Any idea why is that? Are there any differences in Uniswap requirements between Sepolia and Mainnet? How can i debug this to figure out what is causing NonfungiblePositionManager::createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary EvmError: Revert?
I was trying to change INITIAL_PRICE, adjusting coins amounts etc. but nothing has any effect.
Below are foundry logs if thats helpful:
[667662] CoinMinter::mintCoinAndRequestDex(MintParams({ name: "Osteo Pedro", symbol: "PDR", creator: 0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496, team: 0x50e2a33B9E04e78bF1F1d1F94b0be95Be63C23e7, recipients: [0x6CA6d1e2D5347Bfab1d91e883F1915560e09129D, 0x27b8eC2601784563820E931e257972560109F2a8, 0xA3C349EbBaf703EAbb095d91c04105E1b0E861D6], amounts: [90000000000000000000 [9e19], 2000000000000000000 [2e18], 8000000000000000000 [8e18]], totalCoins: 22222222222222222222222222222222 [2.222e31], totalFunds: 100000000000000000000 [1e20], mcd: 0xaBC27F4fa9dae4829575A3DF7958b9d80872c8a8 }))
    │   │   ├─ [584878] → new Coin@0xc3B785939FE923f3EA338Ae6793C99de2671b2cB
    │   │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, to: ManagerStagingTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496], value: 3333333333333333333333333333333 [3.333e30])
    │   │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, to: 0x50e2a33B9E04e78bF1F1d1F94b0be95Be63C23e7, value: 1111111111111111111111111111111 [1.111e30])
    │   │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, to: CoinDexer: [0xaBC27F4fa9dae4829575A3DF7958b9d80872c8a8], value: 9999999999999999999999999999999 [9.999e30])
    │   │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, to: user: [0x6CA6d1e2D5347Bfab1d91e883F1915560e09129D], value: 6999999999999999999999999999999 [6.999e30])
    │   │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, to: user_two: [0x27b8eC2601784563820E931e257972560109F2a8], value: 155555555555555555555555555555 [1.555e29])
    │   │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, to: user_three: [0xA3C349EbBaf703EAbb095d91c04105E1b0E861D6], value: 622222222222222222222222222222 [6.222e29])
    │   │   │   └─ ← [Return] 1825 bytes of code
    │   │   ├─ emit CoinMinted(coinAddress: Coin: [0xc3B785939FE923f3EA338Ae6793C99de2671b2cB], coinName: "Osteo Pedro", coinSymbol: "PDR")
    │   │   ├─ [40831] CoinDexer::dex(Coin: [0xc3B785939FE923f3EA338Ae6793C99de2671b2cB], 100000000000000000000 [1e20], 22222222222222222222222222222222 [2.222e31])
    │   │   │   ├─ emit DexRequestReceived(token: Coin: [0xc3B785939FE923f3EA338Ae6793C99de2671b2cB])
    │   │   │   ├─ [23974] WETH9::deposit{value: 100000000000000000000}()
    │   │   │   │   ├─ emit Deposit(dst: CoinDexer: [0xaBC27F4fa9dae4829575A3DF7958b9d80872c8a8], wad: 100000000000000000000 [1e20])
    │   │   │   │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    │   │   │   ├─ [534] WETH9::balanceOf(CoinDexer: [0xaBC27F4fa9dae4829575A3DF7958b9d80872c8a8]) [staticcall]
    │   │   │   │   └─ ← [Return] 100000000000000000000 [1e20]
    │   │   │   ├─ emit Swapped_ETH_For_WETH(amount: 100000000000000000000 [1e20])
    │   │   │   ├─ [674] NonfungiblePositionManager::createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary(Coin: [0xc3B785939FE923f3EA338Ae6793C99de2671b2cB], WETH9: [0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2], 3000, 7922816251426433759354395 [7.922e24])
    │   │   │   │   └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert

UPDATE:
It seems like newly created coin "0xc3B785939FE923f3EA338Ae6793C99de2671b2cB" address is corrupted somehow. I did not change anything, just added another creation of coin like below:
// Before (Doesnt work)
MemeCoin newCoin = new MemeCoin(params);

// After (Works perfectly fine but both coins addresses are different)
new MemeCoin(params);
MemeCoin newCoin = new MemeCoin(params);


Does anyone has idea if thats foundry issue? It seems like it is just creating corrupted coin address, or maybe that address is somehow used on Mainnet, but I did not find anything in etherscan explorer.
